# Dropdown Menu not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Why is the dropdown menu not working in this piece of code? The list option is being displayed but it appears the "Caret" is not working correctly. Any ideas why?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Retrofit </title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href ="css/main.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content ="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no">
        <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js " </script>
        <script src ="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class ="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div cass ="container"> 
                <a href ="index.php" class ="navbar-brand"> Retrofit </a>
                <ul class ="nav navbar-nav"> 
                    <li class ="dropdown ">
                        <a href ="#" class ="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle ="dropdown"> League <span class = "caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class ="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href ="#"> Premier League </a></li> 
                            <li><a href ="#"> La Liga </a></li>
                            <li><a href ="#"> Bundesliga </a></li>
                            <li><a href ="#"> Serie A </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>   

        </nav>
        <?php
        // put your code here
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add the relevant CSS (like the `caret` class definition) and any JS you are using.

Comment: @RobAllen code updated -

Comment: You really should duplicate the problem with the css loading.. relative paths do not help.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Thank you all the same for the advice

Comment: Your path of css is /main.css and not example.com/main.css, so it can not be duplicated. At first glance, it looks like you could try placing the JS file just before the closing </body> tag.

Comment: I apologize for not being clearer - I wanted to see the specific declarations for `caret`, `dropdown-menu`, `dropdown`, `nav` and `navbar`. It's helpful to know you are using bootstrap. Please also include what you expect to happen, and what does happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting jquery to the bottom of the body
something like this

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```